# Triple boot Windows XP, Ubuntu, & Mac on Acer z5g notebook

Tags: 11.04, boot, windows, mac

I'm planning to install Mac OS X using these instructions

http://basshead.wordpress.com/2010/04/04/snow-leopard-on-acer-aspire-one-aoa150zg5/

on my Acer z5g notebook

I have Windows XP & Ubuntu 11.04 dual booting on it perfectly fine. My question is how do I make triple boot system? What exactly do I need to do for this? Do I need to tweak grub for that?  I'm going to create 30GB partition for MAC OS X. Is it correct thing to do?

EDIT:

i still couldnt get it done..but soon it will be working.for now
follow
http://www.mydellmini.com/forum/dual-booting/14145-triple-boot-videos-guide-using-chameleon-os-x-windows-7-ubuntu-netbook-remix.html
this link will ask u to install mac on 2nd partition but its not clearly mentioned how to do it.so check following.

to install mac on ur sencond partition follow
http://osx.mechdrew.com/guides/macusb_dellmini10v.shtml
i knw u will update to 10.6.8  and not 10.6.4 as told in the blog above(thats what i did)but after that it wont boot(keeps on reebooting) because kernel is not patched for 10.6.8 so follow these to patch the kernel:
http://prasys.info/2011/06/howto-macos-x-10-6-8-and-intel-atoms/

once i m done ill update this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On internet there are tons and tons of methods to get it done but i find the following closest to what i needed

http://www.mydellmini.com/forum/dual-booting/14145-triple-boot-videos-guide-using-chameleon-os-x-windows-7-ubuntu-netbook-remix.html this link will ask u to install mac on 2nd partition but its not clearly mentioned how to do it.so check following.

to install mac on ur sencond partition follow http://osx.mechdrew.com/guides/macusb_dellmini10v.shtml 
i knw u will update to 10.6.8 and not 10.6.4 as told in the blog above(thats what i did)but after that it wont boot(keeps on reebooting) because kernel is not patched for 10.6.8 so follow [this](http://prasys.info/2011/06/howto-macos-x-10-6-8-and-intel-atoms/) to patch the kernel

also while installing win7,it might give you some kinda MBR partitioning error but not to fear thats because partitions are out of sync..you just have to execute command `gptsync` from your ubuntu or MacOSX (i had to install `gptsync` via `apt-get`) and then you are good to go.

note:you might also need to perform one or more steps repeatedly to get the things done,so dont frustrate and keep doing it until you get it right.for me it took almost a whole month of sweat,tears,blood,grief.i also broke BIOS of my netbook making it unable to even start,but as alway google helped me out here is a [link](http://www.leosquarez.com/acer-aspire-one-bios-recovery-acer-aspire-one-zg5-screen-not-working/) to recover BIOS of ACER ZG5

BEST OF LUCK

Answer (score 1):

I've toyed a lot with these kinds of set ups. Let me emphasize that it's a cool project, but be prepared to reinstall everything a few times before you get it right. It's ideal if you can make an image of your drive from states that are good to restore to and try again from.

Now, just looking at the URL you gave, those are looking like somewhat older instructions. So you may want to google around first and see if you can't find something a touch more modern. Grub2 (which is the default boot loader with Ubuntu 11.04) can detect OSX and add it as a boot option. I'd suggest you find some current, decent instructions, follow them fairly closely, but see if you can skip the bootloader installation. Then, when installation is complete, you'll need to regenerate your grub boot menu. I think running `sudo update-grub` will do that for you.

Hope that helps set ya on the right track. Like I said, I've had a few projects along these lines and I found the docs helpful, but I still needed to tinker a bunch, but I eventually tend to get it working, so hopefully so will you!

Comment: hmmm ohk! now i will try to install OSx if it works fine then no issues but if it doesn't then i will have to reinstall all three of them again so in what order should i do that?

Comment: Personally, I'd try OSX first (and put it on a second partition), then Windows (on to a first partition) and the Linux, on to whatever partition. Just what I'd try.

Comment: finally i got it done...also posted the answer!
thanks +1 for you...